# FileExplorer not showing folder for VBE7.dll that does exist (Yes...Hidden folders are being shown)

Tags: vba, windows, filesystems

I am curious to modify the .dll file for VBA based on [these suggestions](https://superuser.com/questions/313408/how-can-i-use-custom-colours-in-the-microsoft-vba-editor) to get a custom color scheme.

When I inspect references in the VBA Editor I see a reference to

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1\VBE7.dll
```

Problem:
Using File Explorer or Chrome, it appears the VBA folder does not exist. There is no VBA folder at

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared
```

Image showing VBA folder does not exist

[image]

In my File Explorer options I have configured to show hidden and protected folders.  I believe it should be showing based on my settings.

My File Explorer Settings 1/2

[image]

My File Explorer Settings 2/2

[image]

How can I find the file at my destination, in order to backup and modify it? Since VBA does work on my machine, I am confident it does exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 32 bit office it would not be there but at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1\VBE7.dll`.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually running 64 bit office.  The C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared path does not contain a VBA directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Office 2019 (Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14326.20850) 32-bit

After running an extensive search for that dll on my entire PC, I found it here:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1\
```